# Error importing statsmodel.api. cannot import specfun

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I've imported statsmodel.api for python 1000 times. Just started getting a random error upon import. Anyone had this error? Code is below.

I am using windows and my python is updated via the conda package.

Thanks all.

```
`import statsmodels.api as sm`
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-6030a6549dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py in <module>()
----> 1 from . import iolib
      2 from . import datasets
      3 from . import tools
      4 from .tools.tools import add_constant, categorical
      5 from . import regression

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\iolib\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .foreign import StataReader, genfromdta, savetxt
      2 from .table import SimpleTable, csv2st
      3 from .smpickle import save_pickle, load_pickle
      4 
      5 from statsmodels import NoseWrapper as Tester

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\iolib\foreign.py in <module>()
     18 import numpy as np
     19 from numpy.lib._iotools import _is_string_like, easy_dtype
---> 20 import statsmodels.tools.data as data_util
     21 from pandas import isnull
     22 

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .tools import add_constant, categorical

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py in <module>()
      7 import numpy.linalg as L
      8 from scipy.linalg import svdvals
----> 9 from statsmodels.distributions import (ECDF, monotone_fn_inverter,
     10                                        StepFunction)
     11 from statsmodels.datasets import webuse

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .empirical_distribution import ECDF, monotone_fn_inverter, StepFunction
      2 from .edgeworth import ExpandedNormal
      3 

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions\empirical_distribution.py in <module>()
      3 """
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
      6 
      7 def _conf_set(F, alpha=.05):

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py in <module>()
    158 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    159 
--> 160 from .interpolate import *
    161 from .fitpack import *
    162 

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in <module>()
     14 import numpy as np
     15 import scipy.linalg
---> 16 import scipy.special as spec
     17 from scipy.misc import comb
     18 import math

C:\Users\rebortz\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    587 
    588 from .basic import *
--> 589 from . import specfun
    590 from . import orthogonal
    591 from .orthogonal import *

ImportError: cannot import name specfun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same issue related to a bad or missing `scipy.special.specfun` in scipy 0.15.1 .  Reverting my version of scipy to 0.14.0 was a workaround and resolved my issue.  Using conda, you can revert using 
`conda install scipy=0.14.0`  Installing from other packages on binstar will also work if 0.15.1 is needed.